# How do you rectify "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null" error?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to implement a menu toggle using javascript. The *getBoundingClientRect().left* was supposed to return a DOMRECT on the left of the menu viewport. But i keep getting the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null
> >at index.js:6

Here is the javascript

```
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
const navOpen = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navClose = document.querySelector(".close");

const navLeft = menu.getBoundingClientRect().left;
navOpen.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (navLeft < 0) {
    menu.classList.add("show");
    document.body.classList.add("show");
    navBar.classList.add("show");
  }
});

navClose.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (navLeft < 0) {
    menu.classList.remove("show");
    document.body.classList.remove("show");
    navBar.classList.remove("show");
  }
});
```

The html

```
<nav class="nav">
    <div class="navigation container">
      
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="top-nav">
          <div class="logo">
          </div>
          <div class="close">
            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
          </div>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#home" class="nav-link scroll-link">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#about" class="nav-link scroll-link">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#services" class="nav-link scroll-link">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#skills" class="nav-link scroll-link">Skills</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#Portfolio" class="nav-link scroll-link">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#contact" class="nav-link scroll-link">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="hamburger">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
/* Nav */
.nav {
    padding: 1.6rem 0;
  }
  
  .nav.fix-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--customColor);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    z-index: 999;
  }
  
  .nav.fix-nav .logo h1 span {
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .navigation {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  .logo h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .logo h1 span {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: var(--customColor);
  }
  
  .nav-list {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .nav-item:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
  }
  
  .nav-link:link,
  .nav-link:visited {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0.8rem 1rem;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .nav-link:hover {
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    background-color: var(--customColor);
  }
  
  .top-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .menu {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: -100%;
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 40rem;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #fff;
      transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
      z-index: 100;
    }
  
    .menu.show {
      left: 0;
    }
  
    .top-nav {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      background-color: var(--customColor);
      padding: 1rem 1.6rem;
    }
  
    .logo h1 span {
      color: #fff;
    }
  
    .top-nav .close {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 2.3rem;
      padding: 1rem;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  
    .hamburger {
      display: block;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 2.3rem;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  
    .nav-link:link,
    .nav-link:visited {
      display: block;
      font-size: 1.7rem;
      color: #222;
      padding: 1rem 0;
    }
  
    .nav-list {
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: start;
      padding: 1rem 1.6rem;
    }
  
    body.show::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      z-index: 1;
    }
  
    .nav.show {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
  }
```

This is my first time asking a question on here, any help will appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `const menu = document.querySelector(".menu"); console.log(menu);` So you are probably referencing the element before it exists. You need to move the script to after the element is rendered on the page or you need to call it onload or document ready. All explained in the duplicate.

Comment: @epascarello thank you very much, it worked. All I had to do was move the index.js script tag from the head of the html file to the bottom.